# Change Key Bindings Individually for Each Layout on Linux

Tags: linux, keyboard, gnome, keyboard-layout

I am on Debian Jessie with GNOME. I prefer to program with the () bound to what is regularly [ and ] because I do a lot of lisp. I was able to do this with xmodmap, but it ruins my other (Portuguese) layout by turning the key that makes letters like:

á é í ó ú.

into the left round bracket "(".

What I would rather do is have each layout bound to it's specific special key bindings so I can have the () and [] switched individually for both layouts, not interfering with each other.

The type of layouts are the [gnome menu bar.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewDu1.png)

Comment: I tried asking stack overflow but they rejected it:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30427262/change-keybindings-without-breaking-other-layouts-linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do this in `xmodmap`. Here are some possibilities...

#### Preferred approaches.

- Customize the English keyboard layout (should be `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us`). Make a copy and the change the original to swap parens and brackets. This shouldn't affect the Portugese layout. You could also try [Keyboard Layout Editor](https://github.com/simos/keyboardlayouteditor) software.

  Some references:

  - [Ubuntu Forums post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=188761&p=1092145#post1092145)
  - [Arch Wiki article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_configuration_in_Xorg)
- If you're using a customizable environment (eg. Emacs) for coding, you could simply rebind the paren and bracket keys to insert the other symbol.

  Eg. in Emacs:

  ```
  (define-key key-translation-map (kbd "[") (kbd "("))
  ;; etc...
  ```

  Or in Vim:

  ```
  imap [ (
  " etc...
  ```

  *Note:* If you can't outright rebind printing keys in your editor, you may well be able to use a text substitution, auto-correction or snippet expansion add-on to automatically replace the characters. (You'll have to check the precise capabilities of the extension to see if it will work for this.)

  For example, in Emacs, apart from the approach above, you could also use `abbrev-mode` autocorrection, or even Yasnippet (if you have it set to automatic and non-recursive expansion).

#### Other approaches.

- Technically, I'm sure you could do it in `xbindkeys`, by binding the keys to a script that checks the current keymap and emulates the appropriate keypress (I don't know if it can do the latter natively; if not you'd need to use something like `xkvbd` or `xdotool`).

  This probably isn't the best approach, though. It would be faster and less error-prone to change the keymap.
- You should be able to do this using [Autokey](https://code.google.com/p/autokey/). It can be used for text replacement. You'd have to do some research to find out how to make it conditional on the current keymap, though.

  Reference: [Lifehacker article](http://lifehacker.com/5310976/autokey-does-customized-text-replacement-for-linux)